# Navigation with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Trying to find the best way to implement navigation using Xamarin.Forms pages.

Here is my UI navigation diagram 
[image: UI navigation diagram]

I am using mvvm. And each of ViewModels populated with INavigationService.

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    private readonly NavigationPage navigationPage;

    private const string PageNameTemplate = "Mmv.MMTravel.CrossPlatform.Views.{0}, Mmv.MMTravel.CrossPlatform";

    public NavigationService(NavigationPage page)
    {
        navigationPage = page;
    }

    public string CurrentPageKey
    {
        get
        {
            return navigationPage.CurrentPage.GetType().Name;
        }
    }

    public async Task GoBackAsync()
    {
        await navigationPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

    public async Task NavigateAsync(string pageKey, object parameter)
    {
        await CallOnNavigateFrom();
        var page = CreatePage(pageKey);
        await CallOnNavigateTo(page, parameter);
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
        {
             Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                navigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            await navigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
    }

    public async Task NavigateAsync(string pageKey)
    {
        await NavigateAsync(pageKey, null);
    }

    public async Task SetAndNavigateToRootPage(string pageKey, object parameter)
    {
        await CallOnNavigateFrom();
        var page = CreatePage(pageKey);
        await CallOnNavigateTo(page, parameter);
        navigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(page, navigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.First());
        await navigationPage.PopToRootAsync(false);
    }

    public async Task SetAndNavigateToRootPage(string pageKey)
    {
        await SetAndNavigateToRootPage(pageKey, null);
    }

    public async Task NavigateModalAsync(string pageKey, object parameter)
    {
        await CallOnNavigateFrom();
        var page = CreatePage(pageKey);
        await CallOnNavigateTo(page, parameter);
        await navigationPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
    }

    public async Task NavigateModalAsync(string pageKey)
    {
        await NavigateModalAsync(pageKey, null);
    }

    public async Task GoBackModalAsync()
    {
        await navigationPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }

    private Page CreatePage(string pageKey)
    {
        var typeName = string.Format(PageNameTemplate, pageKey);
        var pageType = Type.GetType(typeName);
        var page = Activator.CreateInstance(pageType) as Page;
        return page;
    }

    private async Task CallOnNavigateTo(Page page, object parameter)
    {
        var vm = page.BindingContext as INavigateAwareViewModel;
        if (vm != null && !vm.IsBusy) 
        {
            await vm.OnNavigatedTo(parameter).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    private async Task CallOnNavigateFrom()
    {
        if (navigationPage.CurrentPage != null)
        {
            var prevVM = navigationPage.CurrentPage.BindingContext as INavigateAwareViewModel;
            if (prevVM != null && !prevVM.IsBusy)
            {
                await prevVM.OnNavigatedFrom().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, my NavigationService contains NavigationPage. So all navigation happened through Navigation property in NavigationPage.
Also each viewmodel has OnNvaigateTo() and OnNavigateFrom() methods for async init.
When app starts, I set MainPage property in App.cs to navigationPage in NavigatioService

***Question #1***

To implement navigation through pages #1 - #3 (on UI navigation diagram) 
I use *SetAndNavigateToRootPage* method

For example, when user navigate from page #1 INTRO to page #2 ACCOUNT.
[image]

I call InsertPageBefore() method of Navigation property. 
[image]

And then PopToRootAsync() method.
[image]

I found a new way to achieve this. Just to set a MainPage property in App.cs to a new page.

**Please tell me your opinion which way is better?**

- **use SetAndNavigateToRootPage**
- **set MainPage property in App.cs**

***Question #2***

There is a MasterDetailPage (#5)

The problem is, when I navigate from page #3 MAIN NENU to page #5 BurgerMenu, according to my current implementation I have this:

[image]

According Xamarin documentation:

[image]

This is not a good idea to populate NavigationPage with MasterDetailPage...

**I should change my NavigationService and use MainPage property from App.cs instead of putting everything inside NavigationPage, shouldn't I?**

Comment: Yes you are right you must use MainPage property for proper navigation system. But you can face with issues about navigation in android platform. (I remember that some navigation operations not working on android)